# SharePoint 2013 Powershell - Copy File From One Site Collection To Another

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Please can someone assist in helping with the above subject?

I would like to copy one file from a specific folder in a sharepoint site collection to another library (of the same name) in a different sharepoint site collection (but still within the same Web Application).
I have very little Powershell experience and have tried a number of Google searches but cannot seem to find anything that works.

Below is an example of what i have tried to do (lots of Write-Host to try and figure out what is going on) with the error message at the bottom.

```
Add-PSSnapIn "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

## 
#Set Static Variables 
## 

$SourceWebURL = "http://WebAppURL/sites/Area/Master" 
$SourceLibraryTitle = "Web" 
$DestinationWebURL = "http://WebAppURL/sites/OtherSiteName" 
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "Web"
$FileName = "Resources.aspx"

## 
#Begin Script 
## 

$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL 
$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle} 
$dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL 
$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle} 

$DestFolder = $dList.Files

$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder
Write-Host " line 25 -- " $RootFolder  
$collfiles1 = $RootFolder.Files
Write-Host " line 27 -- "$collfiles1
Write-Host " line 28 -- "$DestFolder

Write-Host " line 30 -- "$str = $DestinationWebURL"/"$DestinationLibraryTitle"/"$FileName 
Write-Host  " line 31 -- "$collfiles1.Count
for($i = 0 ; $i -lt $collfiles1.Count ; $i++)
{
    Write-Host " line 34 -- "$collfiles1[$i].Name
    ##Write-Host $FileName
    if($collfiles1[$i].Name -eq $FileName)
    {
    ##  $str = $DestinationWebURL.Url + $DestinationLibraryTitle + "/" + $FileName
        $str = $DestinationWebURL+"/" +$DestinationLibraryTitle+"/"
        Write-Host " line 40 -- "$str
        Write-Host " line 41 -- "$collfiles1[$i]
        $FiletoCopy = $collfiles1[$i].Name
        Write-Host " line 43 -- " $FiletoCopy
        $FiletoCopy.CopyTo($str,$true)
    }
}
Write-Host "Script Completed"
```

The below example gives the error

```
Cannot find an overload for "CopyTo" and the argument count: "2".
At line:44 char:3
+         $FiletoCopy.CopyTo($str,$true)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following PowerShell for your reference, copy a file from one library in site collection to another library in another site collection with fields.

```
Add-PSSnapIn "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

## 
#Set Static Variables 
## 

$SourceWebURL = "http://WebAppURL/sites/Area/Master" 
$SourceLibraryTitle = "Web" 
$DestinationWebURL = "http://WebAppURL/sites/OtherSiteName" 
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "Web"
$FileName = "Resources.aspx"

## 
#Begin Script 
## 

$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL 
#$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle} 
$dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL 
#$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle} 

$SourceFile=$sWeb.GetFile($SourceWebURL+"/"+$SourceLibraryTitle+"/"+$FileName)
$TargetFolder = $dWeb.GetFolder($DestinationLibraryTitle)
#Copy File from the Source
$NewFile = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($SourceFile.Name, $SourceFile.OpenBinary(),$True)

#Copy Meta-Data from Source
Foreach($Field in $SourceFile.Item.Fields)
{
    If(!$Field.ReadOnlyField)
    {
        if($NewFile.Item.Fields.ContainsField($Field.InternalName))
        {
            $NewFile.Item[$Field.InternalName] = $SourceFile.Item[$Field.InternalName]
        }
    }
}
#Update
$NewFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()

Write-host "Copied File:"$SourceFile.Name
```

Reference: [Copy Files Between Document Libraries in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/copy-files-between-document-libraries-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: excellent, worked like a charm.
could i also ask another question that follows this on nicely. 
how would i go about looping through a number of subsites and for each of those subsites copy the same file as we have above?
Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: You can check the reference article above to get more helps.

Answer (score 0):

So in case of large files where file size is greater than 50MB. This script mentioned by @LZ_MSFT will never be able to copy that file may be. In that aspect, you need to chunk the file into small pieces.Here is the PS to copy from source to destination with chunking if file size is greater than 50MB. Plus point for this one script is, it is using Client so it can be used with SP online and on-prem.

```
   Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
   Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    Function UploadFileInSlice ($DestinationCtx, $SourceCtx, $SourceFileUrl, $DestinationFolderUrl, $fileName, $fileChunkSizeInMB) {
    
    # Each sliced upload requires a unique ID.
    $UploadId = [GUID]::NewGuid()

    # Get File by Server Relative URL
    $File = $SourceCtx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($SourceFileUrl)
    $SourceCtx.Load($File)

    # Get file Steam with OpenBinarySteam
    $StreamToUpload = $File.OpenBinaryStream() 
    $SourceCtx.ExecuteQuery()

    # File size in bytes
    $FileSize = ($File).length  

    # Get Destination Folder by Server Relative URL
    $DestinationFolder = 
    $DestinationContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($DestinationFolderUrl)
    $DestinationCtx.Load($DestinationFolder)
    $DestinationCtx.ExecuteQuery()

    # Set Complete Destination URL with Destination Folder + FileName
    $destUrl = $DestinationFolderUrl + "/" + $fileName
    # File object.
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File] $upload

    # Calculate block size in bytes.
    $BlockSize = $fileChunkSizeInMB * 1000 * 1000 
    Write-Host "File Size is: $FileSize bytes and Chunking Size is:$BlockSize bytes"

    if ($FileSize -le $BlockSize)
    {
        # Use regular approach if file size less than BlockSize
        Write-Host "File uploading with out chunking"
        $upload =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($DestinationCtx, $destUrl, $StreamToUpload.Value, $true)
        return $upload
    }
    else
    {
        # Use large file upload approach.
        $BytesUploaded = $null
        $Fs = $null
        
        Try {
            $br = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($StreamToUpload.Value)
            
            #$br = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($Fs)
            $buffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($BlockSize)
            $lastBuffer = $null
            $fileoffset = 0
            $totalBytesRead = 0
            $bytesRead
            $first = $true
            $last = $false
            # Read data from file system in blocks. 
            while(($bytesRead = $br.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0) {
                $totalBytesRead = $totalBytesRead + $bytesRead
                # You've reached the end of the file.
                if($totalBytesRead -eq $FileSize) {
                    $last = $true
                    # Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
                    $lastBuffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($bytesRead)
                    [array]::Copy($buffer, 0, $lastBuffer, 0, $bytesRead)
                }

                If($first)
                {
                    $ContentStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
                    # Add an empty file.
                    $fileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
                    $fileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $ContentStream
                    $fileCreationInfo.Url = $fileName
                    $fileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
                    #Add file to Destination Folder with file creation info
                    $Upload = $DestinationFolder.Files.Add($fileCreationInfo)
                    $DestinationCtx.Load($Upload)

                    # Start upload by uploading the first slice.
                    $s = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$Buffer)
                    Write-Host "Uploading id is:"+$UploadId
                    # Call the start upload method on the first slice.
                    $BytesUploaded = $Upload.StartUpload($UploadId, $s)
                    $DestinationCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                    # fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
                    $fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
                    Write-Host "First patch of file with bytes"+ $fileoffset 
                    # You can only start the upload once.
                    $first = $false
                }
                Else
                {
                    # Get a reference to your file.
                    $Upload = $DestinationCtx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($destUrl);
                    If($last) {
                        # Is this the last slice of data?
                        $s = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$lastBuffer)

                        # End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
                        $Upload = $Upload.FinishUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
                        $DestinationCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                        Write-Host "File Upload Completed Successfully!"
                        # Return the file object for the uploaded file.
                        return $Upload
                    }
                    else {
                        $s = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$buffer)
                        # Continue sliced upload.
                        $BytesUploaded = $Upload.ContinueUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
                        $DestinationCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                        # Update fileoffset for the next slice.
                        $fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
                        Write-Host "File uploading is in progress with bytes: "+ $fileoffset 
                    }
                }

            }  #// while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        Finally {
            if ($Fs -ne $null)
            {
                $Fs.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    return $null
   }

   #URL to Configure, in this case Destination is SP Online site URL
   #Adding up credentials hard-code, you can use Get-Credentails PS command too

   $DestnationSiteUrl = "https://your-domain.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz"
   $DestinationRelativeURL = "/sites/xyz/TestLibrary" #server relative URL here with library Name and Folder name
   $DestinationUserName = "xyz@your-domain.com"
   $DestinationPassword = Read-Host "Enter Password for Destination User: 
  $DestinationUserName" -AsSecureString

#URL to Configure, in this case Source is On-Prem site URL
#Adding up credentials hard-code, you can use Get-Credentails PS command too
$SourceSiteUrl = "http://intranet/sites/xyz"
$SourceRelativeURL = "/sites/xyz/TestLibrary/myfile.pptx" #server relative URL here with library Name and file name with extension
$SourceUsername = "domain\xyz"
$SourcePassword = Read-Host "Enter Password for Source User: $SourceUsername" -AsSecureString
#Set a file name with extension
$FileNameWithExt = "myfile.pptx"

#Get Source Client Context with credentials 
$SourceContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SourceSiteUrl) 
#Using NetworkCredentials in case of On-Prem
$SourceCtxcredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($SourceUsername, $SourcePassword)
$SourceContext.RequestTimeout = [System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite
$SourceContext.ExecuteQuery();

#Get Destination Client Context with credentials 
$DestinationContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($DestnationSiteUrl) 
#Using SharePointOnlineCredentials in case of SP-Online
$DestinationContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($DestinationUserName, $DestinationPassword)
$DestinationContext.RequestTimeout = [System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite
$DestinationContext.ExecuteQuery();

#All Set up, now just call the UploadFileInSlice with parameters
$UpFile = UploadFileInSlice -DestinationCtx $DestinationContext -SourceCtx $SourceContext -DestinationFolderUrl $DestinationRelativeURL -SourceFileUrl $SourceRelativeURL -fileName $FileNameWithExt -fileChunkSizeInMB 10
```